# Android - How to make a reminder notification through user email?

Tags: android, android-studio, email

I wanted to build an app where when I click button on app, it will send a reminder based on specific date (or else we can called it Expiry notification) through email. Is this possible? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply manipulate google calendar event and set up a date. Email will be automatically send.